# How to add audio files for android VideoView streaming video?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

Hi have list of audio files like english, hindi, french for android **.m3U8** video file.
How to attach .mp3 files to the videoView
 1."https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/org.whatsmad.test/audio.mp3" like.. I have a list of files in **.mp3** format for different langues support.
Question is how to attach that files to video view or how to user that files  on video view to achieve multi language video file.

> Java

```
 mp.setOnInfoListener(new MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(5);
            /*mediaPlayer.setAudioSessionId(5);*/
            MediaPlayer.TrackInfo[] trackInfos=mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo();
            Log.e("size of track : ","track info :"+trackInfos.length);
            for(int audio=0;audio<trackInfos.length;audio++){
                Log.e("audio language: ",trackInfos[audio].getLanguage().toString());
                audioTracks.add(trackInfos[audio].getLanguage().toString());
            }

            Log.e("Inside media","Inside media player2");
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the process what I am following here I am getting audio track list like en, dubbing, fr, en,dubbing like that,
Q: Is that are use full to change the audio language or to change the subtitles of video.?

Comment: Simply use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve the user name. DONE.

Comment: Have you attempted doing any part of this?

Comment: yes, but it's not getting

Comment: Please improve your question with a minimal amount of code to reproduce the problem you're facing and a good explanation.

Comment: We are not here to write your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why your are think about it soooo....,
it very simple 
Step:1
First place a Activity with required credentials like EditText for getting a User name then make it as Launcher 
Step:2
Second create a welcome screen, start that welcome screen after user enter some name by using Intent in FirstActivity
That's it here is your app......

Answer (score 2):

If you need that username only in your next activity you can use extras like this

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("KEY", YOUR_VALUE );
                   LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and then you get it like this in HomeActivity

```
Bundle extras;
extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
extras.getString("KEY");
```

If you need to keep this value in all your app you can use SharedPreferences.